# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison : Recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, error-handling

i dont understand why am getting this max depth error . iam trying to find index of number in array using bst recursive approach , below is my code

```
# Binary Search Tree using recursion


def search(arr,target,s,e):
    middle = s + (e - s) // 2

    if s > e:
        return -1

    if target == arr[middle]:
        return middle

    if target < arr[middle]:
        return search(arr,target,s,middle-1)

    return search(arr,target,s,middle+1)


ARR = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
k = search(ARR,9,0,len(ARR) - 1)
print(k)
```

can anyone tell me whats happening in the code block

error block:

> > PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA> & C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
> > c:/Users/admin/Desktop/DSA/recursion/bst.py Traceback (most recent
> > call last):   File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA\recursion\bst.py", line
> > 20, in 
> > k = search(ARR,9,0,len(ARR) - 1)   File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA\recursion\bst.py", line 16, in search
> > return search(arr,target,s,middle+1)   File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA\recursion\bst.py", line 16, in search
> > return search(arr,target,s,middle+1)   File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA\recursion\bst.py", line 16, in search
> > return search(arr,target,s,middle+1)   [Previous line repeated 995 more times]   File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA\recursion\bst.py", line
> > 7, in search
> > if s > e: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Answer (score 0):

The last case should be `search(arr,target,middle,e)`.

The way you have it coded, it always searches the first half of the array, and eventually you reach the recursion limit.

Comment: tried that , with e and e+1 , still its failing     "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\DSA\recursion\bst.py", line 7, in search   
    if s > e:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: I don't understand.  You wrote this code, right?  You're asking _me_ why something is in the code?

Comment: nah its failing there